# get() function getting many multiple same data laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I know that this is a simple question but why am I getting the same records multiple time? I tried using `dd($data)` and it shows me multiple same records. What did I do wrong?

profile.blade.php

```
 @foreach($data as $value) 
  <tr> 
 @if($value->Evaluation_Status == 'No')
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: blue;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
@elseif(($value->blacklist == 'Yes') && ($value->name == $value->Name))
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
 @else 
<th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
 @endif 
 <th> 
 {{$value->Evaluation_Status}} 
 </th> 

<th>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($value->created_at)->format('d/m/Y')}}</th>

 <th><form action="{{ url('/home/'.$value->pi_id.'/delete') }}" method="get"> 
 {{ csrf_field() }} 
 <button type="submit">Delete</button> 
 </form></th> 
 </tr> 

 @endforeach
```

Controller.php

```
   $data = DB::table('personal_infos')
   ->select('personal_infos.id as pi_id','personal_infos.Name','verifications.name','verifications.blacklist','evaluations.Evaluation_Status', 'evaluations.created_at')
   ->join('verifications','verifications.id','=','verifications.id')
   ->join('evaluations', 'evaluations.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id')
   ->where('personal_infos.deleted_at', NULL)
   ->orderBy('personal_infos.created_at', 'desc')
   ->get(); 

    return view('home',compact('data'));
```

Comment: Is suspect `->join('verifications','verifications.id','=','verifications.id')`

Comment: Yup just saw that as well hahaha, it suppose to be verification.id, '=', 'personal_infos.id', wanted to change the question to another

Comment: Is the problem fixed after changing it?

Comment: Yup a careless mistake, is it possible to change the question? Or do I have to create another question

Comment: If you have a whole other question, then create a new one.

Comment: ok, got to wait 90mins hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing

```
->join('verifications','verifications.id','=','verifications‌​.id')
```

to

```
->join('verifications','verifications.id','=','personal_infos.id')
```

in **Controller.php**